# Excel VBA to PowerPoint VBA Parameters

Tags: excel, vba, function, powerpoint

I'm needing to Pass Parameters from Excel VBA to PowerPoint VBA

Within Excel VBA

```
Sub ExcelToPowerPoint()
    Dim pp As Object
    Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    pp.Visible = True
    pp.Presentations.Open "C:\Users\Name\Documents\presentation.pptm"

    pp.Run "Module2.PowerPointFromExcel", "Helen"
End Sub
```

Within PowerPoint VBA

```
Sub PowerPointFromExcel(ByVal Name As String)
    MsgBox "Hello," & Name
End Sub
```

I need to pass the persons Name from Excel to PowerPoint and be able to use that parameter, but currently the parameter is not going through

Comment: "currently the parameter is not going through" - could you please include the code where you are trying to pass the parameter?  And, have you made sure to check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/PowerPoint.Application.Run) for `PowerPoint.Application.Run`, as it is subtly different from [the Excel version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Run)

Comment: ^^^^ `Application.Run` has a *safeArrayOfParams* parameter.

Comment: This is why I'm asking as I'm unsure of how to pass the parameters, even when I do this {pp.Run "Module2.PowerPointFromExcel", "Helen"} it still doesn't go though, and how does the {Application.Run} be ran with params?

Comment: `pp.Run "Module2.PowerPointFromExcel", "Bob"` works for me from Excel vBA

Comment: When I edit the Module in pp it goes through, but when I save and close I get this Error Run-time error -2147188160 (80048240) Application.Run: Invalid request. Sub or function not defined.